# Increase, save and update score into UILabel

Tags: swift, animation, uilabel

I'm creating Puzzle Word game, How do I increase, save, and update score even when the user exits the application? But I want to be adding points on the UILabel and increase after finished animate

**Code:**

```
class QuestionView: UIViewController {

    var score = 0

    func animate(sender: UIButton) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { [weak self] in

            sender.transform = .identity

        }) { (finished) in

            score += 2 // Must be increase by 2

        }

    }

    func createCoins() {

        let lblCoins = UILabel()
        lblCoins.text = "\(score)"
        self.view.addSubview(lblCoins)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After update **score** variable you have to update **lblCoins.text** also.
To save data on disk you can write to file in device documents directory.
Save data on every score change.

This should help you:
http://www.seemuapps.com/read-to-and-write-from-a-text-file-in-swift

After app launching read from file and set your score variable. 
You can do it in **viewDidLoad** for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to keep track of a value (the score) so that you can retrieve it when the user opens the app again. If that's the case, then you can use the [`UserDefaults` database](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults).

`UserDefaults` is excellent for storing small amounts of data, such as scores or user preferences, for example.

The `synchronize` method call shown in the examples below is optional: iOS will automatically make that call from time to time. You can, as shown, manually call it, though, to be sure your score is updated at the appropriate times.

Swift 3.x:

```
// define a constant String name for the key where the score will be stored
// (note: this can be any name you want; I randomly chose "scoreKey")
let scoreKey = "scoreKey"

// even if the key's value isn't Bool, iOS will return 'false'
// if the key hasn't been set or 'true' if it has been set
let scoreKeyExists: Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(scoreKey)

// if no value has been set, yet, then set an initial value 
if !scoreKeyExists {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInt(0, forKey: scoreKey)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

// retrieve the value when needed
let currentScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().intForKey(scoreKey)

// set value as needed
let newScore = 10
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInt(newScore, forKey: scoreKey)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Swift 4:

```
// define a constant String name for the key where the score will be stored
// (note: this can be any name you want; I randomly chose "scoreKey")
let scoreKey = "scoreKey"

// even if the key's value isn't Bool, iOS will return 'false'
// if the key hasn't been set
let scoreKeyExists: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: scoreKey)

// if no value has been set, yet, then set an initial value 
if !scoreKeyExists {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: scoreKey)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

// retrieve the value when needed
let currentScore = UserDefaults.standard.int(forKey: scoreKey)

// set value as needed
let newScore = 10
UserDefaults.standard.set(newScore, forKey: scoreKey)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

And, in order to update your label during the `finish` closure, you'll need to make your label a global variable like your score.

You could add it via Interface Builder as an `IBOutlet`. Check out this tutorial for an example of how to [Connect the UI to Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html).

Comment: Excuse me what's `scoreKey` ??

Comment: `UserDefaults` is a dictionary with key-value pairs. In order to store and retrieve a value, you need to invent a `String`-type key name. `scoreKey` is the name I invented for the key to store the score. (I forgot to include that definition in my answer, so I'll udate that now.)

Comment: Note also, just to be clear, that the examples I gave don't necessarily all go together. For example, you would set the key name constant globally. Then, you can use it anywhere you need to retrieve the key's value. You would check for existence of the key before using it, or when your app launches if you're going to set an initial value on first game play, say. Then, set or retrieve the value wherever you need to do so for your game to work properly.

Comment: Sorry this code it's not working and it's not increase score into label !! Do you have another solve ?? @leanne

Answer (score 0):

This my solve:

```
func animate(sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { [weak self] in

        sender.transform = .identity

    }) { (finished) in

        score += 2
        lblScoreCoins.text = String(score)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(lblScoreCoins.text, forKey: "Key")

    }

}
```